# Don't highlight UIImageViews in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that contains some UIImageViews that have highlighted image states. I do not want these images to become highlighted when the user taps on the collection view cell. The highlighted states are set in code based on other factors.

How can I get the cells to not set the image views to highlighted when the cell is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Override setHighlighted in your `UICollectionViewCell` class:

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    self.imageView.highlighted = NO;

}
```